# update and delete in the same table

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.5

in my project i have table(images). there is checkboxes column, when the user check record and press delete button record will be deleted. thats work fine.

then there is visible column(boolean) which is by default(true). So when record is checked and click hide/show button it will update visible value(from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1)

My problem is that, delete and show/hide buttons work individually. i want both work at the same time. I don't know how combine them in the same table.

this is my view(in which only show/hide work)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteImg"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
<form action="{{url('admin/images/hideimg')}}" method="post" class="form-inline">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                {{method_field('post')}}
                <div class="pull-right form-group" style="padding: 12px">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning"  id="hideImg">
                        Hide/Show</button>
                </div>


            @if($images)

                <table class="table panel panel-default" id="table">
        <thead class="panel-heading">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="options"> </th>
            <th>Visible?</th>
            <th>photo</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody id="tablecontents" class="panel-body">


                @foreach($images as $image)

            <tr class="row1" data-id="{{ $image->id }}">
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="option" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="{{$image->id}}" data-imageid="{{$image->id}}"></td>
                <td>{{$image->visible == 1?'yes':'no'}}</td>
                <td  ><img src="/uploads/{{$image->path}}" id="img" ></td>
                  <td>

                     </td>
            </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>

    </table>

            @endif

            </form>
```

form action="delete/images" method="post" class="form-inline">

```
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('delete')}}
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title"  style="text-align: center" id="modalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete the following service?</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_all" value="Delete">
                        <span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify the exact problem ie .any errors or image not getting cropped; better post the controller code as well because it's not clear if you are storing image directly in database table or as a file on the server.

Comment: My problem is that I don’t know how to pass the cropped image to my database

Comment: there is no error, this example work perfectly. when i change several thing to pass the cropped image to the controller it gives me an empty array.